# Learning reversing via C++, but what does this line do?

Tags: c++, typedef, hwnd, stdcall, lpcstr

```
typedef int(__stdcall *__MessageBoxA)(HWND, LPCSTR, LPCSTR, UINT);
```

As I said, im trying to learn how to reverse engineer programs using C++ / Assembly, so I'm going through some open source projects I found on the internet. But can anyone explain what this line does? Im not advanced in C++, which is why I'm going through sources.

Comment: Any context? A link to the project's source code?

Comment: http://www.mediafire.com/download/cpcemq1kemn1r8t/CodeCave.cpp

Comment: this declares a type named `__MessageBoxA` that is a pointer to a function returning `int` and parameters `HWND, LPCSTR, LPCSTR, UINT` whose calling convention is `__stdcall`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is C language. So it also compiles fine in C++.

Let 's go step by step.

1. Here is a **function declaration or prototype or signature**.
   It returns an int, accepts 4 parameters :

```C++
int __stdcall MessageBoxA(HWND, LPCSTR, LPCSTR, UINT);
```

2. Here ptr is a **pointer variable to a function** :

```C++
int(__stdcall *ptr)(HWND, LPCSTR, LPCSTR, UINT); 
ptr = NULL;
/ assign a correct adress
ptr = MessageBoxA;
// call the function with parameters using the pointer
(*ptr)(hWnd, NULL, NULL, 0);
```

3. Here **__MessageBoxA is a type** that helps to define a variable that is a pointer to a function:

```C++
typedef int(__stdcall *__MessageBoxA)(HWND, LPCSTR, LPCSTR, UINT);
```

So a pointer to a function  variable can be declared.

```
__MessageBoxA ptr1 = NULL;
```

__stdcall is the way the function is called by the compiler ( Are parameters passed from left to right or reverse ? Is return value passed through stack memory or CPU register ?) - details most people don't care as long as caller and called agree

Regards